# Django save integer not null primary key value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am using django to develop my application.  A landmark model class has integer not null primary key field (gid).  I want to insert max(gid) + 1 value to that field but  can't set it as auto increment.   What is the best solution? I thot override save() in model so that i don't want to explicitly assign value to the gid field.

Plz help me to do it in efficiently...

Thanking you ,

Answer (score 0):

Try latest

```
MyMobel.objects.latest('gid').gid + 1
```

This will take the latest value. Be careful to check if the model has no objects. In that case, set the `gid` to the first value you want